# How to locate a urdf file using parser.AddModelFromFile(full_name); in Drake

Tags: c++, robotics, drake

```
#include "drake/geometry/scene_graph.h"
#include "drake/multibody/parsing/parser.h"
#include "drake/common/find_resource.h"

int main(void) {
// Building a floating-base plant
    drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double> plant_{0.0};
    drake::geometry::SceneGraph<double> scene_graph;
    std::string full_name = drake::FindResourceOrThrow(
        "model/model.urdf");
    drake::multibody::Parser parser(&plant_, &scene_graph);
    parser.AddModelFromFile(full_name);
    plant_.Finalize();
    return 1;
}
```

The above code give me the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Drake resource_path 'model/model.urdf' does not start with drake/.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My Directory layout is:

- Project Folder

  - model

    - urdf
  - src

    - main.cpp
    - CmakeLists.txt

my src CmakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
message("CMAKE Directory : " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

project(IK VERSION 1.0)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
find_package(drake CONFIG REQUIRED)

# specify the main source file
set(SOURCE main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE})

target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" 
    Eigen3::Eigen
    drake::drake}
```

Essentially, my objective is to use a custom urdf and build a model and use it for the inverse kinematics class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a very easy problem to resolve. You're currently using `drake::FindResourceOrThrow()`. If you look at [its documentation](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake.html#a535bb41fc091d96d7de06b87e68c9afb), you'll note:

> The resource_path refers to the relative path within the Drake source repository, prepended with drake/.

You have a urdf in an arbitrary location. In that case, just pass a filesystem path without calling `FindResource()` (or any of its variants). Whether it is an absolute or relative path will depend on where your executable ends up w.r.t. the urdf in your built/installed system.

Comment: As an example: [drake-external-examples](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/blob/7cb73ccecbcae5412ab619ff6c61afd708f8eb5e/drake_cmake_installed/src/find_resource/find_resource_example.cc); see usages also in Tutorials and Examples from Drake website: https://drake.mit.edu/